# Mongo nodejs replicaset big query optimisation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I have a nodejs app connected to a mongodb database (1 master 2 slaves)

The app is working great, each hour there is a script running taking a lot of resources on mongodb.

I do not really know if this is normal but seems that each query is going through the master then I do not know what mongo is doing internally but when the script is running mongo master slave is becoming crazy and the other do not move

This is the status of my replica set

```
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:22.555Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(91),
        "syncingTo" : "",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(91)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14.201Z"),
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(91)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14.201Z"),
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(91)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(91)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14.201Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14.201Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
        "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
        "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
                "lastElectionReason" : "stepUpRequestSkipDryRun",
                "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2020-08-28T16:55:35.926Z"),
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(91),
                "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1598633735, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(90)
                },
                "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1598633735, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(90)
                },
                "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
                "priorityAtElection" : 1,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
                "priorPrimaryMemberId" : 0,
                "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
                "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2020-08-28T16:55:35.931Z"),
                "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2020-08-28T16:55:38.029Z")
        },
        "electionParticipantMetrics" : {
                "votedForCandidate" : true,
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(90),
                "lastVoteDate" : ISODate("2020-08-22T21:11:10.366Z"),
                "electionCandidateMemberId" : 0,
                "voteReason" : "",
                "lastAppliedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1598129847, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(89)
                },
                "maxAppliedOpTimeInSet" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1598129847, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(89)
                },
                "priorityAtElection" : 1
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "mongo-1.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 1697606,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(91)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(91)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:22.026Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:21.990Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "mongo-2.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-2.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 7810311
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongo-2.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 2200677,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(91)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(91)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:21.291Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:22.033Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncingTo" : "mongo-0.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "mongo-0.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "syncSourceId" : 3,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 7810311
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "mongo-0.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 2200701,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(91)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-09-17T08:29:14Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1598633735, 2),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2020-08-28T16:55:35Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 7810311,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"viqVgd9SZDI2Q3NB0sz5lJo4xBM="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6834562805081833474")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1600331354, 1)
}
```

I am connection mongo with `MongoClient.connect`

and the url is `mongodb://username:password@mongo-0.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-1.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-2.mongo.live.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&slaveOk=true`

Can you please let me know if my replica and connection is normal.
I do not understand why only master cpu is going up

An other solution could be to add a new master only for my script, is it a good approach ?

Comment: There is some useful info in the docs: [Troubleshoot Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/) and [Replica Set Read and Write Semantics](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/applications/replication/). You can include additional info to your post about the script that is taking lot of resources.

Comment: All queries go through "primary" instance which you call "master" for some reason. It's how mongo is designed. There is a way to run read queries on secondaries https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/ if you are happy with risk of reading stale data. All writes go to the primary only, no options.

Answer (score 0):

@prasad_ Thanks for the help

`readPreference=secondaryPreferred` to my connection url and now the read request are dispatched between my two secondary